# best way to include header and footer on HTML using any client side framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Having HTML project want to include header and footer , so it will reduce rework. 
Please suggest any good way.

I tried AngularJS with ng-include and below code

```
var app = angular.module("arstlApp", []);
app.controller("arstlCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope,$timeout) {
  $rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
    $timeout(function(){
         _autoload();
    });
  });
});
```

but `<ng-include` increase number of call JS function.

Answer (score 1):

try this i may `<Menu-Header></Menu-Header>` on the every page for header

Or

`<header ng-include="'includes/header.html'"></header>`

also this for footer

Answer (score 0):

You specify "any client side framework" but every framework has it's own way of doing this. For angular you could for example look into having a layout page and changing the body content via `<ui-view/>`.

Or you could handle this via the stateProvider:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('test', {
            url: '/test',
            templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
            header: {
                template: '<h1>Header</h1>',
                controller: function($scope) {}
            },
            footer:  {
                template: '<p>Footer</p>',
                controller: function($scope) {}
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

use ui-router like this :

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
        $stateProvider
        .state('root',{
          url: '',
          abstract: true,
          views: {
            'header': {
              templateUrl: 'header.html',
              controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
            },
            'footer':{
              templateUrl: 'footer.html',
              controller: 'FooterCtrl'
            }
          }
        })
        .state('root.home', {
          url: '/',
          views: {
            'container@': {
              templateUrl: 'homePage.html'
            }
          }
        })
        .state('root.other', {
          url: '/about',
          views: {
            'container@': {
              templateUrl: 'aboutPage.html'
            }
          }
        });    

    }]);
```

and in index.html :

```
<header>
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
</header>
<div ui-view="container">
</div>
<footer ui-view="footer">
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly don't care about the which framework: Consider using [pug](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html).

Example from link:

```
doctype html
html
  include includes/head.pug
  body
    h1 My Site
    p Welcome to my super lame site.
    include includes/foot.pug
```

Other options:

- Use a component based client framework like AngularX or React
- pug is just one of the many Html template libraries out there (Handlebars, Vue, ...)
- If you have a semi-static website, [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) will create static html from your source files with support for html includes
- Use PHP or another server side language which supports includes. Or use some MVC framework in said language (ex PHP has Laravel)